Getting stackoverlow error while executing a recursive function
I'm trying to remove consecutive duplicate numbers in a Linked List using recursion. My code is working fine for smaller size of Linked Lists but getting Stack Overflow error for bigger size Linked lists. I am not able to figure out what the issue might be.
/*

    Following is the Node class already written for the Linked List

    class Node<T> {
        T data;
        Node<T> next;
    
        public Node(T data) {
            this.data = data;
        }
    }

*/

public class Solution {

    public static Node<Integer> removeDuplicates(Node<Integer> head) {
        //recursive approach
        if(head==null || head.next==null){
            return head;
        }
        Node<Integer> smallAns = removeDuplicates(head.next);

        if(smallAns.data.equals(head.data)){
            return smallAns;
        }else{
            head.next = smallAns;
            return head;
        }
    }
}

Sample Input 1 :
1 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 5 5 7 -1
Sample Output 1 :
1 2 3 4 5 7 


Maximum stack depth is limited which means that for any amount of stack there exists a large enough list that leads to a stack overflow. Do you have a number for how big the list is that leads to a stack overflow?

For recursion you need a function that calls itself with different parameters than the previous invocation. And you need a criteria when the function would not call itself again. If you do not do this, the function would repeatedly call itself without limitation and overrun any size of stack.

@queeg correct, but which of these is missing in posted code?

@ThomasKläger I am coding at a platform where they don't show the inputs they are providing. My code is passing 4/6 test cases. However, I checked the code for smaller size linked list and that was working fine.

@queeg I have added the base case where the recursion will eventually stop once it reaches the end of the linked list.

They don't provide you all the inputs, but often times they tell you about the limits (for example, leetcode has a similar problem and they tell you that the input list has at most 300 nodes)

Ok, so this is the constraint they have provided 0 <= M <= 10^5
Time Limit: 1sec, where M is the size of Linked List.

Please provide the link to the code challenge. Time limits only make sense on a given machine. The time needed on our own PCs will be very different.

If you have a stack overflow error, it means in this case you are making to many nested recursive calls, which practically means you need to use a different algorithm.

different algorithm -> maybe a non-recursive one (10^5 recursive calls are a lot. Usually you can extend the maximum size of the stack, but probably not on a remote site)

Your algorithm is correct, but the error indicates that the recursion goes so deep as to reach the call stack limit.
This means you have to look for another algorithm that doesn't allocate O() space on the call stack.
Here is iterative implementation:
    public static Node<Integer> removeDuplicates(Node<Integer> head) {
        if (head == null) {
            return head;
        }
        // tail is the last node of the partition that has no duplicates
        Node<Integer> tail = head;
        // curr is the first node of the partition that has not yet been processed
        for (Node<Integer> curr = head.next; curr != null; curr = curr.next) {
            if (curr.data != tail.data) {
                tail = tail.next = curr;
            }
        }
        tail.next = null;
        return head;
    }


Thanks for the help.This means that even if our recursive algorithm is correct, we might get stackoverflow error for some cases that are large enough. And in that case we have to go with the iterative approach.

Yes. The available call stack space is limited.
